# Erro ao criar Classe no Eclipse Android

Tags: android, eclipse

Quando vou criar um novo projeto no `Eclipse` `Android` ele mostra os seguintes erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Detalhe: Só baixei as `apis` 4.0 e 4.2 e outras mais inferiores + os extras e `build tools`.

Comment: Seria interessante você mudar para o android studio já que a google não está mais dando suporte ao Eclipse adt

Comment: Eu pensei nisso tb mas o Android Studio é muuuuuuuiiito lento e trava muito... mas já resolvi o problema. O meu erro era pq eu n estava importando a biblioteca appcompat_v7. Daí eu fui em propriedades e defini o meu project com target como ANdroid 6.0 que é o mesmo do AppCompat_v7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo que baixe a versão mais actual do Android SDK que neste momento é a 6.0.

No AndroidManifest.xml coloque o seguinte:

```
android:minSdkVersion="7"
targetSdkVersion="23"
```

Se não quiser baixar a 6.0 coloque `targetSdkVersion="17"` para a versão 4.2.2 ou `targetSdkVersion="19"` para a versão 4.4.2 mas terá de eliminar a pasta `\res\values-21` para se ver livre dos erros.

Se está a começar a programar para Android utilize o Android Studio, o Eclipse ADT deixou de ter suporte por parte da Google.

Comment: Obrigado brother!